# Unit testing Solidity JS

Tags: solidity, javascript, unittesting

I want to test these 3 different require in my mint function with Javascript.

```
function mint(uint256 _mintAmount) public payable {
    require(_mintAmount > 0, "need to mint at least 1 NFT");
    require(_mintAmount <= maxMintAmount, "max mint amount per session exceeded");
    require(supply + _mintAmount <= maxSupply, "max NFT limit exceeded");
```

I'm really new to testing so I tried something like this. obviously its wrong but how can I test that it requires more than 0 _mintAmount in a function like this

```
it('mint amount', async () =>{
    _mintAmount > 0;
    _mintAmount <= maxMintAmount;
    supply + _mintAmount <= maxSupply;
})
```

also tried something like this:

```
also tried something like this:

it('mint amount', async () =>{
    var _mintAmount = await NFT.mint(_mintAmount);
    assert.equal(_mintAmount, _mintAmount > 0);     
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the unit-testing you commonly want to make sure that you get the output that you were expecting. You already have all the checks you wanted in the `mint()` function, now in the unit tests lets make sure that they work, ie `mint(0)` would return `"need to mint at least 1 NFT"`

You can do this by using `assert.equal()`

```
it('mint amount', async function () {
            try { 
               await myContract.mint.sendTransaction(0);
            } catch (err) {
                 assert.equal("need to mint at least 1 NFT", err.reason);
            }
});
```

By using try and catch to get the revert error messages you can check for expected output for any input you want.